# How to print a certain characters from string in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How can I print certain characters from string by subtracting some characters from whole string.

```
ggc-clusterdb01.rvd.ukd.com   ggc-clsdb02.rvd.ukd.com     gg-akb.rvd.ukd.com
```

How can I subtract the characters  like `'01.rvd.ukd.com'` or `'02.rvd.ukd.com'`,`'03.rvd.ukd.com'`..etc from above hostnames  and print the remaining name like `ggc-clsdb` or `ggc-clusterdb`.

I have tried in many ways but with no luck. Help me with an example.

Comment: State those "many way" you tried, in the question. You could have tried [unix.se] for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove a suffix pattern from a string use the syntax: `${parameter%%word}`.

Example:

```
$ foo=ggc-clusterdb01.rvd.ukd.com
$ echo ${foo%%01.rvd.ukd.com}     
ggc-clusterdb
```

You can use a wildcard as well:

```
$ echo ${foo%%0*.rvd.ukd.com}     
ggc-clusterdb
```

To remove everything after the dot:

```
$ echo ${foo%%.*}
ggc-clusterdb
```

Explanation from `man bash`:

> `${parameter%%word}`
>
> **Remove  matching suffix pattern**.  The word is
>   expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the
>   pattern matches  a  trailing portion  of  the  expanded  value  of 
>   parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of
>   parameter with the shortest  matching pattern  (the  ''%''  case)  or
>   the longest matching pattern (the ''%%'' case) deleted.

Comment: Your answer is better, I'll remove mine

Comment: to remove everything after the dot, use echo ${foo%.*}